Why does my shader lose quality when rendering?
I use a BSDF connected to a color ramp to color my object in a stylized way. In the 3D viewport with Rendered Shading, the frontiers between shades on the object show the curves of my object. However, when I render it using F12, the result I get is very different: the curves do not appear anymore, the shades are very rough and seem more rectangular than they should.

I feel like this may be related to the configuration of my light, but I am unable to solve the problem by tweaking the settings.

My object has a subdivision modifier:

Disabling it makes the render faithful to what I see in the 3D Viewport:

It also has a displace modifier:


But even if I disable it, there is still a problem with the render:

Also, I am rendering the scene with EEVEE (I cannot use Cycles because it does not support the "Shader to RGB" shading node that I need):


You probably have a subdiv surface modifier with different settings for preview and rendering.

You may also have different settings for Denoising between the Viewport and Rendered view.

@Lutzi I do have a subdiv surface modifier, and I tried tweaking its settings, but unsuccessfully. However I tried applying the modifier, and it did solve the problem. The rendered image now corresponds to what I see in the 3D viewport. Is there a way to not have to apply it ?

@JohnEason I searched for "denoising" and it seems to be a render option for Cycles. However I am using EEVEE (Cycles does not support the "Shader to RGB"  node that I use in Shading).

I'm 90% sure it's about the subdiv surface. You can update your question with a screenshot of it. I have no idea what to recommend without seeing it.

@papillon That's why you should give as many details of your setup as possible in your question. You didn't mention you were using EEVEE. Now please add an image of your subdiv modifier panel as Lutzi requests or at least check that the  Viewport and Render Levels on it are the same.

@JohnEason I'm not going to include millions of informations concerning my project right from the start, that would make my post unreadable. I put the ones I thought were likely to be useful. If someone needs more info, like how is my subdivision modifier configured, they can ask.

@Lutzi I included these informations, along with a few others (rendering engine and displace modifier).

You have 2 different resolution on your subdiv surface. Set both to 6 and that's it.

@papillon I didn't ask for 'millions of informations'. As Lutzi says your Subdiv modifier has the Viewport Level set to 6 and the Render Level set to 2 which is enough to cause what you are seeing. Actually 6 seems very high to me. I don't think I've ever needed to use more than 3, but both do need to be the same. In fact you often want to use a lower Viewport level so that you don't get too much lag when modelling.

Thank you it solves my problem!
